# Java Declaring ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, declaration

Sometimes I see ArrayLists declared like

```
ArrayList<String> str;
```

while other times I see it done like

```
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Is there any difference between the two? Or are the same and is one just preferable to use over the other?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> str
```

This is just variable declared

```
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It is initialization of str variable with default size 10.

Answer (score 1):

In the first one there is just a declaration of the object while in the second one you do initialization too.

There is no constraint on the place in which you should initialize an object except that it should happen before trying to access the object.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet is just *declaring* the `ArrayList` (and it's `null` at this point), the second one is declaring *and instantiating* it. There isn't any significant difference, IMHO the second version is more useful, so you won't risk forgetting to instantiate the object.

Comment: Is there any difference or anything wrong with lets say: private ArrayList<E> someList = new ArrayList<E>; as an instance variable, vs declaring as instance variable, then creating in constructor? Does this go against convention or is there absolutely no difference?

Comment: They're equivalent. But sometimes you want to just declare the attribute and instantiate it later, as needed, not necessarily in the constructor.